# How to access to samesite cookies in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies, session-cookies

I've developed an internal service to track users. My service inserts an `<iframe>` that connects to a tracking backend, which sets a cookie with `samesite='none'`. This allows me to track users. The setup works well in Chrome, but I encountered issues when testing the same approach in Firefox. I attempted to resolve this by adding the `sandbox=allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-scripts allow-same-origin` attribute to my `<iframe>`, along with some `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers, but unfortunately, these efforts were not successful.

The primary objective here is cross-domain tracking, involving three or more domains that need to recognize when a user has visited them before.

I've also come across news that Chrome is planning to implement a special policy regarding cross-domain cookies. Do you have any suggestions for resolving this issue in Firefox, or are there alternative methods to achieve cross-domain tracking?